# Preferred way to setup and run code in Application_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0, webactivator

What is the preferred way to hook up and run some code in Application_Start and Application_Endrequest without having to put the code in the MvcApplication class each time?

Maybe there is an event, an attribute or something I can hook up in asp.net 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a correct statement that "*lets you hook up code to run before the application gets compiled.*"

WebActivator classes that you create actually get compiled into the assembly, but allow you to hook into 3 events at run time:

1.) PreApplicationStartMethod
2.) PostApplicationSTartMethod
3.) ApplicationShutdownMethod

**From David Ebbo's desciption:**

*"WebActivator is a NuGet package that allows other packages to easily bring in Startup and Shutdown code into a web application. This gives a much cleaner solution than having to modify global.asax with the startup logic from many packages."*

Using WebActivator is not limited to startup code for just other packages, it can also be used for startup code (bootstrapping) for your application as well.

For instance, I use it to set up and configure my Unity dependencies, my Combres setup, and my 51DegreesMobi setup in a recent project I completed using MVC3. It allows me to have a separate class file for each of those without cluttering up or entering a single line of code in Global.asax.

It is also a much better alternative to the .NET 4 PreApplicationStartMethod in that you can have many classes that have the WebActivator.PreStartupMethod and they will ALL run prior to App-Start, as opposed to the .NET 4 attribute in which I believe you're only allowed to use once.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of [events on the HttpApplication class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication?view=netframework-4.8). However, you still need something that will bootstrap the event hookup.

You could take a look at [PreApplicationStartAttribute](https://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx/). It lets you hook up code to run before the application gets compiled (though the Application instance will not be available that early).

David Ebbo also created a similar system called [WebActivator](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119183955/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/davidebb/archive/2010/10/11/light-up-your-nupacks-with-startup-code-and-webactivator.aspx).

Comment: I don't think I can setup the EndRequest event if I use PreApplicationStartAttribute but maybe with the WebActivator

Comment: To hook up to EndRequest, write an IHttpModule and register it in Web.config in the <modules> section.